# Python - Allow Argparse to Accept an Option in an Argument

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I've been trying to pass a command to argparse, however passing something like `pacman -R` always ignores `-R`. I'm using `.parse_known_args()` to try and solve this, but it still doesn't work. I'm also using nargs='*' to have an unknown amount of arguments
Here's an idea of my desired output:

```
>>> parser.parse_args() # Input: cmdname pacman -R sudo
['pacman', '-R', 'sudo']
```

Current output:

```
>>> parser.parse_known_args() # Input: cmdname pacman -R sudo
['pacman']
```

How would I pass options (e.g. -R -S) as an argument? It doesn't matter if you use .parse_args() or .parse_known_args()

Edit: Sample code:

```py
import argparse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('arguments', nargs='*', help='Arguments to run')
    args, extra = parser.parse_known_args()

    commands = ''.join(args.arguments)
    print(args.arguments, extra)
    os.system(commands)

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Comment: How are you handling `pacman`?  Normally `-R sudo` is treated as one argument, resulting in `Namespace(R='sudo')` or `Namespace(R=['sudo'])`.  The '-R' is a flag for an `optional`, that takes 0 or more arguments (strings) depending on the `nargs` and `action`.  During debugging print `args` and `extras`, so you have a clear idea what the parser has done.  For questions it's a good idea to show a full parser, with actual results.

Comment: @hpaulj Added that! Sorry, at the time I wanted to keep what I was doing to myself. I added an example very similar to what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: import argparse
In [2]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
   ...: parser.add_argument('arguments', nargs='*', help='Arguments to run')
```

`argparse` interprets '-R' as a flag, so `arguments` only gets the strings up to that point.  The rest goes into `extras`.  That's deeply ingrained behavior in `argparse`:

```
In [3]: parser.parse_known_args('pacman -R sudo'.split())
Out[3]: (Namespace(arguments=['pacman']), ['-R', 'sudo'])
```

You can use a '--' to force the handling of all following strings as arguments

```
In [4]: parser.parse_known_args('-- pacman -R sudo'.split())
Out[4]: (Namespace(arguments=['pacman', '-R', 'sudo']), [])
In [5]: parser.parse_known_args('pacman -- -R sudo'.split())
Out[5]: (Namespace(arguments=['pacman', '-R', 'sudo']), [])
```

Comment: So basically: this is just how argparse functions, and there's no way around it code-side?